# Show $R(x)=o(x^3)$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

[image]

I got $$R(x)=4! \, x^4 \int _0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+xt)^{5}}e^{-t} \, \, dt$$ is this correct?

I have no idea what to do for the last part of ii

Comment: What is $n$ in your expression for $R(x)$? Re (ii), this question essentially asks you to regurgitate the relevant section of your notes.

Comment: Your $R$ looks reasonable, though I didn't check it. The condition for being asymptotic is the other way around, $a_{n+1}(x)=o(a_n(x))$, so that the next term is much smaller than the most recent term, provided $x$ is close enough to zero. The condition for being asymptotic to $a(x)$ should, if I'm not mistaken, just be that $a(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero. The error doesn't *have* to be smaller than the first neglected term, although it frequently is. You should check your notes and/or your reference to be sure, though.

Comment: "this question essentially asks you to regurgitate the relevant section of your notes." Yes, it's worrying that you thought best to ask here for something like this, it's just a definition.......

Comment: @David I only made this thread for the last part of (ii) tbh lol

Comment: @David So after integrating by parts with $|R(x)|$, am I right to say that $|R(x)|=o(x^n)$? Then from this, how can we say $R(x)=o(x^3)$?

Comment: The function $R(x)$ is defined by the equation $I(x) = 1 - x +2x^2 - 6x^3 + R(x)$. The $R(x)$ that you wrote at the end of your answer depends on $n$. Nothing else in the equation depends on $n$, so how did one show up in your $R(x)$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Im sorry, what do you mean by "how did one show up in your $R (x) $"? Is my R wrong?

Comment: I am struggling to show $R(x) =o(x^3)$, where my notes IS NOT helping.

Comment: Trying to do a little teaching here for how you should be thinking about the problem: The expression you have to $R(x)$ is pretty suggestive -- can you guess its asymptotic behavior? What was the question asking, again? You should write down (all in one place, which you have not done yet here) what you need to show. Can you simplify that at all? What *specific* estimates do you need to do to solve the problem in the end?

Comment: You're getting stuck at some part of that process. But where?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Well integrating $R(x)$ again I get: $$R(x)=4!x^4 - 5! x^5 \int _0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^6} \, dt $$ I can see that since $x$ is going to zero, the $R(x)$ looks smaller than $x^3$. But I know that I need to show $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{R(x)}{x^3}=0$ which would show $R(x)=o(x^3)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas But how can you evaluate that limit without integrating the remainder term(s). That is what the problem is.

Comment: I have my exam tomorrow so I'm panicking.

Comment: You don't have to integrate by parts again. Try doing it from the original version of $R(x)$. I'll say again: Write down, IN ONE FORMULA, what you need to show. Can you simplify it at all?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Need to show $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^3}=4! \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5}\, dt=0$$ I just hit the brick wall again... How can we evaluate that.

Comment: Ok, good, except that the limit should be as $x \to 0^+$, not as $x \to 0$. Then, here's how you should be thinking about it: Clearly $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$. What about the integral? Is it possible to bound it in some way? Maybe you can try using the squeeze theorem. Can you find an upper bound of the integral **which does not depend on $x$?**

Comment: @AntonioVargas Ignoring the $4!$: $$0 \le x \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5}\, dt \le  x \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5} \, dt + x \int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5} \, dt \le  x \int_1^{\infty} {e^{-t}} \, dt = \frac xe$$

Comment: Then take limit from both sides?

Comment: Looks great! "Then take limit from both sides?" Not the phrasing I would use. Use this instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: Once you've done that then you're totally done! Post your complete answer below and I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I done it. Thanks a lot. Although I do feel that this is a little harsh for gaining only one mark though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to show $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^3}=4! \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5}\, dt=0$$ so we need to show $$ A= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^5}\, dt=0
$$ Then
 $$0 \le A \le  x \int_0^{\infty} {e^{-t}} \, dt = x
$$ so $$0 \le A \le x$$ Then since $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}0 =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x =0$$ then by squeeze rule, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} A=0$$

Comment: I didn't notice it in your comment, but why do you split the integral into two parts? Once you do, how does the next inequality follow?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Because I thought when something is being divided, if the variable is below 1, it gets larger and when the variable is above 1, it gets smaller. But I think I see that we don't have to...

Comment: Well, $1+xt \geq 1$ for all $x,t \geq 0$, so there's no "below $1$" in this problem.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Oh yeah, thanks. Changed it.

Comment: Awesome, great job.